# How to find how much steps up and to the side by knowing angle and steps

Tags: geometry

Let's say you know how long a line is and where it's pointing.

By knowing that how do you find how much steps a line extends downward and to the side by knowing the line length and angle?

For example: an line that is 4 feet long and extends at an 35 degree angle.
How far does the line extend out to the right and up?

Comment: Do you now any trig?   The goes up $4\sin 35^\circ$ and to the right $4\cos 35^{\circ}$.

Comment: How much background do you have?  Have you learned any trigonometry?  Please **edit your question** to provide this information, and to show us your own independent efforts to solve the problem.  That's important because problems that don't show an effort to reach a solution independently are often downvoted and closed.

Comment: And $\sin 35^{\circ} \approx 0.57357643635104609610803191282616$ so $4\sin 35\approx 2.28$ and so to the right is $\sqrt{4^2 - 2.28^2}\approx 3.29$ which is approx $4\cos 35 \approx 4\times 0.81915204428899178968448838591684$

Comment: Im making a game with this btw and Im just eight grade...

Comment: You'll have to teach yourself the concept of trig.

Comment: Note that it matters how the angle is measured. The usual assumption in pure math is that the positive $x$-axis is direction zero and a positive angle represents something rotated in a counterclockwise direction from the zero direction. But compass directions on a map typically work differently from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a circle centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $1$.  Now imagine all the points of the circle labeled as $(x,y)$ and they all satisfy the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1^2$.

Now imagine that for every point $(x_1, y_1)$ draw the line from $(0,0)$ to $(x_1,y_1)$.  That point will have a specific angle $\theta_1$.  ANd vice versa.  If you imagine an angle $\theta_2$, line for $(0,0)$ at that angle will hit the circle at exactly on point $(x_2, y_2)$.

So because there is a one-to-one correspondence there is function between angles and points defined like that.

There is no way to use algebra to figure it out but we do have a function and we make a list of all those values and we used to right them down in books but now we program them into caluculators and program languages.

There are two functions.  If you take and angle $\theta$ and imagin a line at that angle from $(0,0)$ at that angle, and extend it a distance of $1$ it will hit a circle at $(x_\theta, y_\theta)$.  We call $x_\theta = \cos (\theta)$ and wee call $y_\theta = \sin (\theta)$.

So you want to find $4\times \cos 35^\circ$ is how for it goes over, and $4\times \sin 35^\circ$ is how far it goes up.

If you punch into a calculator $\cos 35$ you get $0.81915204428899178968448838591684$ and if you punch in $\sin 35$ you get $0.57357643635104609610803191282616$.  (Notice that if you square and add them they add up to $1$.  Thats because they are the $x,y$ values of a point on a circle).

So you want $4\times 0.819= 3.276$ and $4\times 0.573=2.292$.

Notice that $3.276^2 + 2.292^2\approx 16_{\text{with small rounding error}} = 4^2$ so it satisfies Pythogorean Theorem.

The branch of mathematics called Trigonometry is *entirely* about these functions.

A few things to note:

$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$.  Always.

And two.  If you have a point $(x,y)$ on a sheet of paper and your rotate it by $\theta$ angles and you want to know where $(x,y)$ end up.... well, that can be solved by figuring out what ange $\alpha$ has $\sin \alpha =y$ and $\cos \alpha = x$.  Figuring out what the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(0,0)$ is $r=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and figuring the new angle is $\alpha + \theta$ and the new point is $(r\cos(\alpha + \theta), r\sin(\alpha + \theta))$.

Trigonometry is *very* useful for these types of problems.